# Exception when JSON data is displayed in JSP

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets, gson

I am trying to display JSON data in JSP and I am trying to display JSON data in JSP for the first time.

Data is fetched from database and I have the following code in Servlet

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Employee> employee = myDAO.getEmpDetails("SMITH");
        JsonElement element = 
            gson.toJsonTree(employee, new TypeToken<List<Employee>>() {
                }.getType());
        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
```

and in JSP I am calling as

```
$.get('myservlet',function(responseJson) {
            if(responseJson!=null){
                $("#empTable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                var table1 = $("#empTable");
                $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                     var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                        rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['empNo']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['empName']); 
                        rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['empAddress']);                          
                        rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                });
                }
            });
```

The problem I am having is when I am calling my servlet class I am getting the follwing exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(TypeToken.java:84)
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:61)
at test.net.MyService$1.<init>(MyService.java)
at test.net.MyService.doPost(MyService.java:101)
at test.net.MyService.doGet(MyService.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The stacktrace sounds like a GSON problem, not a JSP problem.

Comment: What version of Gson are you using? Also, you should be able to serialize your list directly (without a type token) using `new Gson().toJson(employee);`.

Comment: @Perception I am using `gson-2.2.2.jar`

Comment: @Perception Directly using means by doing as `Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Employee> employee = myDAO.getEmpDetails("SMITH");        String empJson = gson.toJson(employee);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(empJson);
        response.getWriter().write("");` If so how can I use this in JSP to display results?

Comment: @Polppan - Your code sample for 'using directly' is ok and should get rid of your servlet side error. As far as displaying the results on the page (via Javascript) what problem are you now having? Side note, I did find [this link on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-gson/h5ybkIuny0Y/RWWmKfHkh-EJ), which may be relevant to your original problem.

Comment: @Perception When I am directly calling, there are no servlet errors. Issue is not able to display results in JSP.

Comment: @Polppan - thats a separate, Javascript issue. I would recommend asking another question directly related to that. Show in it, your generated JSON, and the Javascript you have above.

Comment: @Perception My issue has been resolved, thanks. If you could post an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Polppan - Np, I've added answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [Google search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-gson/h5ybkIuny0Y/RWWmKfHkh-EJ) revealed a possible source for the problems related to use of the `TypeToken` class. If you are using ProGuard or a similar compiler tool that removes type information from parameterized classes then it is possible for the token initialization to fail in the way shown. However, while you track down and resolve that issue, it is entirely possible to serialize your data list without using a token:

```
List<Employee> employee = myDAO.getEmpDetails("SMITH");

String json = new Gson().toJson(employee);   // Note use of `toJson` method
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().print(json);
```

This should eliminate any source of error on your servlet side, and as long as your Javascript code works, then you should be good to go.